# Amazon MWS API - How do you call SubmitFeed when your meteor and npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-mws

I am running this code from meteor. I currently call

```js
import { mws } from 'mws-nodejs';
import Future from 'fibers/future';

const getASINDetails = (asin) => {
  let future = new Future();
  console.log("getting ASIN.....", asin);

  mws.products.GetMatchingProduct(
    {
      "SellerId" : sellerID,
      "AWSAccessKeyId" : AWSAccessKeyId,
      "SecretKey" : SecretKey,
      "MWSAuthorizationToken" : MWSAuthToken,
      "AmazonServicesURL": "mws.amazonservices.com"
    }, {
      MarketplaceId: MarketplaceId,
      ASINList: {
          'ASINList.ASIN.1': asin
      }
      }, true, function (err, data) {
      
        console.log("do something with the data");
      
      }
  );
  return future.wait();
};
```

If i then want to call SubmitFeed() from mws.

I can't figure out the right syntax to execute the function pass in the amazonenvelope:

```js
let sXML = `<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amznenvelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>PartialUpdate</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>UNIQUE-TO-ME-1234</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>ASIN</Type>
                <Value>B000A0S46M</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <Condition>
                <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
            </Condition>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>`;
```

I am thinking the code should be something like this?
But have not idea as I can't figure out their API...

How do i call SubmitFeed() and pass the XML?

Also how do i know if Submit feeds is available from mws.product

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: nope... any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Try this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-mws, I had prepared some of the examples using this library. It does support promise, callback including different EcmaScript version. You can try that out. If it didn't work, share me your code sample of your solution, I can help you out for that library.